# the fast clicking on a picture

Tags: vb.net, button, click, picturebox

[this is a game I am creating called: "Click the apple" its in dutch btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X2Yv.png)

im a beginning programmer, so I am making this game but I am trying to add some grafics and im trying something in photoshop, this is what i came up with, I like it alot, now the problem when I put a click event on the picutebox (the apple) and I make it increment a label each time i click it it just works fine, but when i click to fast it cant keep up (also I used a fast clicker but its just slowly incrementing) when i do this same thing but with a button it works just fine now i want to know whats the problem, maybe some of you guys can help me, ill paste the code here:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim appels As Integer = 0
    Dim aps As Integer = 0
    Dim apc As Integer = 10

    Dim ug_1_multiplier As Integer = 2
    Dim ug_1_prijs As Integer = 1500

    Dim appelstruik_prijs As Integer = 100
    Dim appelstruik_aps As Integer = 1
    Dim appelstruik_aantal As Integer = 0
    Dim appelstruik_max As Integer = 20

    Dim appelboom_prijs As Integer = 200
    Dim appelboom_aps As Integer = 5
    Dim appelboom_aantal As Integer = 0
    Dim appelboom_max As Integer = 10

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        L_appelstruiken_prijs.Text = appelstruik_prijs
        L_aant_appelstruiken.Text = (appelstruik_aantal & " / " & appelstruik_max)

        L_appelbomen_prijs.Text = appelboom_prijs
        L_aant_appelbomen.Text = (appelboom_aantal & " / " & appelboom_max)

        T_aps.Start()
        T_testformax.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
        PictureBox2.Enabled = False
        PictureBox2.Enabled = True
        appels = appels + apc
        L_aant_appels.Text = appels
    End Sub

    Private Sub B_appelstruik_kopen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_appelstruik_kopen.Click
        If appels >= appelstruik_prijs Then
            aps = aps + appelstruik_aps
            appels = appels - appelstruik_prijs
            appelstruik_prijs = Math.Round(Val(appelstruik_prijs / 10), 0) + appelstruik_prijs
            appelstruik_aantal += 1

            L_aant_appelstruiken.Text = (appelstruik_aantal & " / " & appelstruik_max)
            L_appelstruiken_prijs.Text = appelstruik_prijs
            L_aps.Text = aps
            L_aant_appels.Text = appels
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("je hebt: " & appels & " van de: " & appelstruik_prijs)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub B_appelboom_kopen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_appelboom_kopen.Click
        If appels >= appelboom_prijs Then
            aps = aps + appelboom_aps
            appels = appels - appelboom_prijs
            appelboom_prijs = Math.Round(Val(appelboom_prijs / 10), 0) + appelboom_prijs
            appelboom_aantal += 1

            L_aant_appelbomen.Text = (appelboom_aantal & " / " & appelboom_max)
            L_appelbomen_prijs.Text = appelboom_prijs
            L_aps.Text = aps
            L_aant_appels.Text = appels
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("je hebt: " & appels & " van de: " & appelboom_prijs)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub T_aps_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles T_aps.Tick
        appels = appels + aps
        L_aant_appels.Text = appels

        L_aant_appelstruiken.Text = (appelstruik_aantal & " / " & appelstruik_max)
        L_appelstruiken_prijs.Text = appelstruik_prijs

        L_appelbomen_prijs.Text = appelboom_prijs
        L_aant_appelbomen.Text = (appelboom_aantal & " / " & appelboom_max)

        L_aps.Text = aps
        L_aant_appels.Text = appels
    End Sub

    Private Sub T_testformax_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles T_testformax.Tick
        If appelstruik_aantal >= appelstruik_max Then
            B_appelstruik_kopen.Enabled = False
        Else
            B_appelstruik_kopen.Enabled = True
        End If

        If appelboom_aantal >= appelboom_max Then
            B_appelboom_kopen.Enabled = False
        Else
            B_appelboom_kopen.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub B_gen_appels_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_gen_appels.Click
        appels = appels + apc

        L_aant_appels.Text = appels
    End Sub

    Private Sub b_upgrade_1_apc_dubbel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b_upgrade_1_apc_dubbel.Click
        If appels >= ug_1_prijs Then
            apc = apc * ug_1_multiplier

            L_apc.Text = apc

            b_upgrade_1_apc_dubbel.Enabled = False
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("je hebt: " & appels & " van de: " & ug_1_prijs)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Click event for it. If you need to get the number of clicks, use MouseClick Event. It has MouseEventArgs like argument. This class has like properties: Clicks, that returns the number of times the mouse button was pressed and released.

Comment: I dont know if you use visual studio but when you are in the design view and dubbleklick on something you get the code like:http://pastebin.com/KNBg8t0h, i did the same thing with the picturebox but its incrementing slower (relative to how fast I am clicking)

Comment: When you realize double click in control, you get the code like image. But, it's just the default event of the controle.  In up side screen you will see two droplists. One will be writing "Click". Change it for "MouseClick" . One new sub will show.

Comment: I changed it to "MouseClick" but it does the same thing, later I changed it to "MouseDown" and the problem was fixed, thanks I appreciate your help. Sorry for my bad english, :P haha